# Overlay interrups hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

**UPDATE:**

Was requested to include my HTML, note that this is using Handlebars for my NodeJS code:

```
<div id='grid'>
    {{#each projects}}
        <img src='{{image_path}}' id='image-{{id}}' class='gridImage'>
        <div id='overlay-image-{{id}}' class='overlay'>
            <div class='detail'>
                <span style='font-size: 18px; font-family:OpenSans-Bold'>{{name}}</span>
                <br><br>
                {{shortDescription}}
                <br><br>
                Made by {{developers}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

---

I have a grid of images, when you hover over each image, it'll tell you something about the image using a div overlay. [Like this.](https://cloudup.com/cFyWL1f3Xk2p)

Now, here's the jQuery code to do that:

```
$('.gridImage').mouseover(function() {
    $('#overlay-'+$(this).attr('id')).css({
        'top': $(this).position().top, 
        'left': $(this).position().left,
        'right': $(this).position().left, 
        'bottom': $(this).position().bottom,
        'width': $(this).width(),
        'height': $(this).height()
    }).fadeIn(150);
});
$('.gridImage').mouseout(function() {
    $('#overlay-'+$(this).attr('id')).fadeOut(150);
});
```

Essentially, this code detects when you hover over the image, it finds the right (div) overlay based on which image it is (id), and smacks it on top of the image. Now because the div completely covers the image, `mouseout` is called and causing the overlay to fade out.

Pretty simply, this makes it so I put my mouse over the image, it fades in the overlay and then fades it out - basically it flickers

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the mouseout event straight on the overlay instead of the image. 
I also feel like there is probably a better solution for this using some CSS

Comment: Yep - let me try that. How would I use CSS though? Since there are many overlays with different id's and I need the right one.

Comment: This would only work if you are guarenteed that the mouse will be on the overlay when the overlay comes up.  If the mouse could start over your original element, but outside the overlay, then this won't work for all mouse positions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `mouseover` / `mouseout` to `mouseenter` / `mouseleave`.

**Edit**

Here is the jsfiddle I was using:

http://jsfiddle.net/ax9X5/2/

**Edit 2**

Since `.overlay` isn't a child element of `.gridImage`, the above solution requires both to be put as child elements in a container and move ID and mouseenter to that container.

Have fun!

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, but it makes all the difference for this http://jsfiddle.net/ax9X5/2/. Sorry if I got it wrong.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if someone would explain why this isn't working. As far as I can see it does everything it's supposed to.

Comment: Basically, since the overlay covers the original element (image), it cancels the hover.

Comment: Wasn't the problem that `mouseout` was called when the overlay was fading in? Have you looked at my jsfiddle that compares `mouseover` with `mouseenter`? I don't mind beeing down voted, but I still think my answer works. Or maybe I just haven't had enough morning coffee :)

Comment: @MagnusEngdal Yes. Your code does work! Huzzah! Thanks so much :-)

Comment: Great :) I was beginning to doubt myself there for a minute because of all the down votes.

Comment: @MCKapur Note that I haven't taken width and height into consideration, but the basic concept should be there.

Comment: @MCKapur Bummer. Well, then I guess moving mouseleave from the grid to the overlay might work (http://jsfiddle.net/jF7hZ/4/). Still, the difference between mouseover and mouseenter is nice to know :) Good luck!

Comment: @MagnusEngdal This kinda works, but it has some weird quirks. Sometimes it flickers, sometimes the fades don't work, sometimes the overlay sticks. 

So weird lol

Comment: Strange, seems to work ok in jsfiddle. Not sure if I can be of more assistance, but hopefully you have some pointers in the right direction now.